# Batch script calling a powershell function

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

Is there a way for a batch file to call a powershell function? I've tried

```
powershell ". .\tes.ps1; Test-Me -Param1 'Hello world' -Param2 12345"
```

And it works, the function gets called, but so does everything else in the powershell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is dot-source **tes.ps1** so that you can use the **Test-Me** function that's defined in that file. When you dot-source a file, everything in that file gets executed. If you have other commands in **tes.ps1** that you don't want to execute, then you'll need to put **Test-Me** in a separate file. The best way to do that: Create a file called **Test-Me.ps1** that contains the contents of the function (*don't* declare a function with `function { [...] }`, just include the code inside the function's scriptblock), then invoke it like this in your batch file:

```
powershell "<path>\Test-Me.ps1 -Param1 'Hello world' -Param2 12345"
```

Comment: Passing the whole command line as a single string to powershell should work, but I'd prefer using the `-File` option: `powershell -File "C:\path\to\Test-Me.ps1" -Param1 "Hello world!" -Param2 12345`.

Answer (score 0):

@Adi Inbar 's solution works perfect.

Here is another way (more from structuring standpoint): If tes.ps1 only contains functions, create a brand new script with following contents:

```
.\tes.ps1
Test-Me -Param1 'Hello world' -Param2 12345
```

Then in batch file, run this brand new script with the "file" parameter:

```
Powershell -file *path_to_PS_script*
```

The tes.ps1 run first it will load all functions in the script scope. You can pick which function to run.

In this way tes.ps1 file serves as a central library of functions.

Comment: I'm inferring that **tes.ps1** doesn't just contain functions, because he says that "everything else in the powershell script" also gets called. If it contained only functions, then dot-sourcing and calling the function as he's doing would work fine.

Comment: @Adi Inbar What I got from the question is that he/she only want to call the specific function and doesn't want "antything else gets called".

Comment: Right. And if it were all function definitions, nothing would get called except functions he invokes explicitly after dot-sourcing. If, as he says, other things from the script file are executed when he dot-sources it, then it's not all function definitions.

Comment: I guess it is not clear when he says "but so does everything else in the powershell script.". If my guess is right, it means: 1.variables being "loaded" to the session. 2. Other functions being "loaded" to the session. When you dot-sourcing a script, this is true that all variables and functions in the script will be "loaded" although they might not be "called" specifically.  I have a feeling that he/she takes "being loaded" as "executed" but it is a assumption. @user2526047 if you can please clarify this.

Comment: @Adi you are right. I was under the impression that doc-sourcing only load the variable/function to the environment. No it "execute everything" in the script. Thanks.